# expected trait object `dyn Responsability`, found type parameter `T`

Tags: rust, trait-objects

I am trying to implement a responsability chain in Rust:

[link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=941081e963ff2c6e16bea80ca1fd5086)

```rust
use std::error::Error;

struct Query {
    query: String,
}

struct Response {
    response: u64,
}

trait Responsability {
    fn take(&self, iterator: std::slice::Iter<Box<dyn Responsability>>, query: Query) -> Result<Response, Box<dyn Error>>;
}

struct ResponsabilityChain<T: Responsability> {
    responsabilities: Vec<Box<T>>,
}

impl<T: Responsability> ResponsabilityChain<T>
where
    T: Responsability,
{
    pub fn new(responsabilities: Vec<T>) -> Self {
        let responsabilities = responsabilities.into_iter()
            .map(|elt| Box::new(elt))
            .collect();
        
        Self { responsabilities }
    }
    
    pub fn launch(&self, query: Query) -> Result<Response, Box<dyn Error>> {
        let iterator = self.responsabilities.iter();
        let responsability = iterator.next().unwrap();
        
        responsability.take(iterator, query)
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

The infamous message is:

> Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground) error[E0308]: mismatched
> types   --> src/main.rs:35:29    | 19 | impl<T: Responsability>
> ResponsabilityChain    |      - this type parameter ... 35 |
> responsability.take(iterator, query)    |
> ^^^^^^^^ expected trait object `dyn Responsability`, found type
> parameter `T`    |    = note: expected struct `std::slice::Iter<'_, Box<(dyn Responsability + 'static)>>`
> found struct `std::slice::Iter<'_, Box<T>>`    = help: type parameters must be constrained to match other types    = note:
> for more information, visit
> https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#traits-as-parameters
>
> For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
> error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error

I do not understand why the compiler complains expecting `Box<dyn Responsability>` while having `Box<T>` since I specify `T: Responsability`. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dyn I` and `<T> where T: I` are different types in Rust, so the compiler complains since there's no implicit conversion.

`T` is a concrete type determined at compile time. `dyn I` it is a "trait object", it is dynamic, and concrete type is unknown, but sort of carried within.

> A [good video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xcygqF5LVmM) on the topic.

Conversion from `<T> where T: I` to `dyn I` is not free, it has a runtime cost, so has to be explicit with the Rust's philosophy.

The code could be fixed by using `Vec<Box<dyn Responsability>>` in all places. It will also allow you passing arbitrary types to `new()`, which is probably what you want, because `Vec<T>` has to contain objects of the same type (remember that this type is determined at compile time).

Comment: I could find a workaround but I went into the Box problem. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: According to what you wrote, I found [a working solution](https://gist.github.com/rust-play/d96640f6e2477fa35aa08d234c476faf) it is much simpler than I though initialy. Thank you very much for your explanation, it was clear as fresh water.